# NMDS plot using species

Tags: r

I am using species cover data and environmental data to plot NMDS in 2D and 3D plot using VEGAN package.I can plot NMDS based on sites, but when i try to plot by NMDS

```
" species scores not available
Error in order(x) : argument 1 is not a vector"
```

error pops up. I also tried using `warscores=T`, but the problem exists. I have following data types:
Species Data. I also tried to group the data by treatment using ordihull but it wont draw polygon either.

I can do species richness, even i can plot NMDS but without species scores. following is the species data

```
Row Labels  Acalypha gracilens  Acalypha virginica  Acer rubrum Acer saccharum  Adiantum pedatum    Ageratina altissima Agrimonia rostellata    Amelanchier arborea Amphicarpa bracteata    Anemone virginiana  Antennaria parlinii Antenoron virginiana    Aralia spinosa  Arisaema dracontium Arisaema triphyllum Asimina triloba Asplenium platyneuron   Athyrium filix-femina   Botrypus virginianus
2014PL1 0   0   0   3.5 0   0   0   0   15.5    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2014PL10    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2014PL11    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2014PL12    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2014PL13    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3.5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2014PL14    0   0   0   0.5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2014PL15    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   15.5    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2014PL16    0   0   0   0.5 0   0   0   0   0.5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2014PL17    0   0   0   15.5    0   0   0   0   0.5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2014PL18    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2014PL19    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3.5 0   0   0
2014PL2 0   0   0   3.5 0   0   0   0.5 3.5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2014PL20    0   0   0   3.5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   63  0   15.5    0
```

And Environment data looks like

```
    Treatment   elevation   slope_per   AspectDir   PPT TMEAN   TMIN    TMAX    sprichness  shanentrop  invsimpson
2014PL1 Burn First  181 56  North   1070    13  7   18  6   4.00621539  3.2647854
2014PL10    Thin First  170 21  Southwest   1070    13  7   18  11  3.596290814 3.212736502
2014PL11    Burn First  181 11  North   1070    13  7   18  5   2.733395222 2.081998115
2014PL12    Control West    159 14  Southwest   1070    13  7   18  3   1.919417872 1.592798768
2014PL13    Control West    168 16  South   1070    13  7   18  17  7.633877547 6.004748813
2014PL14    Control East    168 26  Northeast   1070    13  7   18  11  4.062814017 2.995957554
2014PL15    Control East    180 8   Northeast   1070    13  7   18  13  6.689341767 5.228200972
2014PL16    Burn First  170 46  Southwest   1070    13  7   18  9   2.711557879 1.755060729
2014PL17    Thin First  176 26  South   1070    13  7   18  7   2.621677069 2.050662739
```

Code:

```
## Import species data and environmental data##
comm <- read.table("species.csv",header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep=",")
singleton_Comm<- comm[,colSums(comm>0)>1, drop=F]
#comm_wis_trans<-wisconsin(singleton_Comm)
dm_matrix<-vegdist(singleton_Comm)
#Generate stress values for 1-4 dimensional NMDS and make scree plot
ord1d<-metaMDS(dm_matrix, distance = "bray", k = 1,wascores=TRUE, trymax = 100)
#print(ord1d$stress)
ord2d <- metaMDS(dm_matrix, distance = "bray", k = 2,wascores=TRUE, trymax = 100)
#print(ord2d$stress)
ord3d <- metaMDS(dm_matrix, distance = "bray", k = 3,wascores=TRUE, trymax = 100)
#print(ord3d$stress)
ord4d <- metaMDS(dm_matrix, distance = "bray", k = 4,wascores=TRUE, trymax = 100)
#print(ord4d$stress)
#stress<-c(ord1d$stress, ord2d$stress, ord3d$stress, ord4d$stress)
#plot(stress, xlab = "Number of Dimensions", ylab = "Stress")

stress<-c(ord1d$stress, ord2d$stress, ord3d$stress, ord4d$stress)
##Plotting stress of different ordination##
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
stressplot(ord1d)
stressplot(ord2d)
stressplot(ord3d)
plot(stress, xlab = "Number of Dimensions", ylab = "Stress")


##Importing the Environment Variables##
environment <- read.table("environment.csv",header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep=",")
env<-data.frame(environemnt[1:11])

##Vector fitting environment variables and richness index with 3rd ordination because only 3rd ord has less than0.2 stress##
vectors1 <- envfit(ord2d, env, na.rm = TRUE, permu = 999, choices = 1:2)
vectors <- envfit(ord3d, env, na.rm = TRUE, permu = 999, choices = 1:3)

#Plotting NMDS using 2D species score and sites
ordiplot(ord2d, choices = c(1, 2), type="points", display = "sites", xlim = c(-0.5,0.7), ylim = c(-0.5,0.5),
         cex = 0.7)
ordiplot(ord2d, choices = c(1, 2), type="points", display = "species", xlim = c(-0.5,0.7), ylim = c(-0.5,0.5),
         cex = 0.7)

#fitting ordihull
ordihull(ord2d,groups=env$Treatment,draw="polygon",col="red",label=T)

#Plotting using 3D
ord3dplotyear <- ordirgl(ord3d, display = "sites", choices = 1:3, col = c(rep("red"), rep("orange"), rep("yellow"), rep("green")))

ord3dplotyear <- ordirgl(ord3d, display = "species", choices = 1:3, col = c(rep("red"), rep("orange"), rep("yellow"), rep("green")))


ordihull(ord2d,groups=treatment,draw="polygon",col="red",label=T)
```

I am expecting a NMDS plot showing species scores and treatment, species scores and elevation and so on

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Please post a sample data if possible (I cannot simply copy and paste the one in your question because there´re spaces in between the species names).

Comment: Have you tried to use "Acalypha_gracilens" instead of "Acalypha gracilens"?